# HTML Validation Issue with <head>

Tags: html, validation, header, w3c-validation

I performed a W3C HTML validation on a client's website and it's saying I have closed the header tag too early. This gives errors stating I have placed meta and link tags outside the header.

Can someone please advise what is wrong with my headers?

**WARNING:** Adult site NSFW

**VALIDATION:** http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hush-hush.com%2F1stflick%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Nude Teen Videos | 1st Flick - Week 624</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22415623-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>

    <meta name="google-translate-customization" content="c6d5b23c329fcd9b-06d3de73510dc63e-g0ea7962122bd05dd-11"></meta>

    <!-- Start Alexa Certify Javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript">_atrk_opts = { atrk_acct:"9AYbi1acVE0008", domain:"hush-hush.com",dynamic: true};
            (function() { var as = document.createElement('script');
            as.type = 'text/javascript';
            as.async = true;
            as.src = "https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js";
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s);
            })();
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <img src="https://d5nxst8fruw4z.cloudfront.net/atrk.gif?account=9AYbi1acVE0008" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
        </noscript>
    <!-- End Alexa Certify Javascript -->

    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie6.css" media="screen"/>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/js/pngfix.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie7.css" media="screen"/>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="alternate" title="Hush-Hush Galleries: News &amp; Updates" href="http://www.hush-hush.com/feed.xml" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <meta name="Description" content="1st Flick amateur teen video download. Submit vid to win password or cash."></meta>
    <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="movies, movie, video, videos, softcore, 1st Flick, teen, download, password, bedroom, amateur, adult, voyeur, downblouse, nipple, nipple slip, nip slip, upskirt, hidden camera, topless, celebrity nude"></meta>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
...
```

Comment: The heck is that? a porn SITE? hahaha

Comment: Porn people have problems too, I suppose.  Do you have meta tags after the header is closed?

Comment: hmm.looks very interesting..

Comment: @MatthewJohnson there are no meta tags after the header is closed.

Answer (score 3):

`<noscript>` elements aren't permitted as children of `<head>` elements.  They can only appear within `<body>` elements.

Comment: Thanks. That's strange because Alexa instruct the inclusion of their snippet inside all page's headers.
Will the <noscript> tag prematurely close the header though?

Comment: In HTML, the start and end tags for the `<head>` and `<body>` elements are optional.  If a parser comes across an element that can't be present in the `<head>` element, it infers that the `<head>` element must have ended and the `<body>` element must have begun.  Then, when it reaches an element that can only appear in the `<head>` element, it's an error condition.  However this is not HTML, this is XHTML, which doesn't have optional start or end tags, meaning as soon as the parser sees an element that doesn't belong in the `<head>` element, it's an error condition.

Comment: So to answer your question, no, in this situation it doesn't prematurely close the header.  That's the error you have when you are using the more flexible HTML.  The error you have when you are using XHTML occurs sooner.  Either way, Alexa's advice is bad and you shouldn't be using code like this.

Answer (score 1):

In **HTML 4.01** (or **XHTML 1.0**) the [`noscript` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1) must not be used in the [`head` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#h-7.4.1).

In **HTML5** it would be [allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element):

> **The `noscript` element**
>   […]
>   **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   In a `head` element of an HTML document, if there are no ancestor `noscript` elements.

But note that if used in the `head`, it must not contain any other elements than `link`, `style`, or `meta`. So you [cannot use the `ìmg` element as child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530682/1591669).

In **XHTML5** it’s not allowed.

---

> Will the `<noscript>` tag prematurely close the header though?

Probably. If the parser finds a `noscript` element, it assumes that the `body` must have started. But of course it *may* be possible that everything works as intended (except for being invalid).

I assume that it should work fine to use your `noscript` in the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just move the `<noscript>` into the body?