# Errors validation W3C HTML5 img noscript facebook.com

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation, noscript

I am trying to validate my page as HTML 5 (W3c). And I have the following error: The "img" element is not allowed here (as a child of the "noscript" element). The "noscript" element, when a child of "head", must contain only the following child elements: "link", "style", and "meta".

On site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration recommendation for my code:
"Copy and paste the upgraded code snippet between `<head>`; and `</head>`; in the HTML code of your website where you want to track conversions. For example, to track registrations, place the code on your 'registration completed' web page."

please see the source code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = '1234567890';
fb_param.value = '10.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=1234567890&value=10.00&currency=USD" /></noscript>
</head>
```

Is it possible to modify this code and pass validation (in head section)?

Comment: You cannot put content in the head. However, you can move the noscript to the body.

Answer (score 3):

W3C’s HTML5 specification defines the content model of a [`noscript` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element) in the `head` element like this:

> […] in any order, zero or more `link` elements, zero or more `style` elements, and zero or more `meta` elements.

As you can see, it cannot contain anything else than `link`/`style`/`meta` elements.  So no, it’s not possible to modify anything to allow an `img` inside of a `noscript` element inside of the `head` element.

But you can have an `img` inside of `noscript` if you place the `noscript` element in the `body`, as the content model is in that case:

> transparent, but there must be no `noscript` element descendants.

*Transparent* means that it has the same content model as its parent element. So for example, if the `noscript` is inside a `div`, it may contain anything that a `div` may contain (except of another `noscript`).

Answer (score -1):

As @Aplet123 and @unor say, you can move the `<noscript>` element to the body. I've done this on my pages, and it appears to work without ill effect.

To check, I've used the Facebook Pixel helper from Chrome, and it behaves exactly the same as the previous version of my page with the `<noscript>` element in the head as per the Facebook sample code.

Finally, to keep the HTML validator happy, you will also need to add an `alt="Facebook pixel"` or similar to your `<img>` element.